# How to run CL.exe using Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, process.start, cl.exe

I have following code

```
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"f:\trial.cpp"))
{
    outfile.Write(txtCode.InnerText);
}

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"cl.exe", @"  'trial.cpp'");

procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.UserName = "asdasd";
SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "abcded")
{
    secureString.AppendChar(c);
}
procStartInfo.Password = secureString;
// Do not create the black window.
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"f:\";
// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();

// Get the output into a string
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

How to pass file name as parameter? Above code doesn't run and I have tried all full path, different path options.

can anyone help?

Comment: doesn't run? what is the error??

Comment: Define "doesn't run". Explain _exactly_ what **is** happening and what you expect to happen.

Comment: What does "doesn't run" mean? Process not started? Wrong command line parameters?

Comment: Swap '@"f:\trial.cpp"' with a string parameter?  In addition, ensuring that the file exists before you process it can resolve issues, e.g. if ( new System.IO.FileInfo( yourFileAndPath ).Exists )...

Comment: "Doesn't run" means, it does not produce any output. Just "Trial.cpp" in result string, which means nothing. I checked the directory where trial.cpp resides, and it has no putput file, checked in cl.exe directory as well as c:\windows\system32, no output.

Comment: maybe since CL is a command line, you could try to start CMD.EXE passing cl.exe as the paramater.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is set incorrectly. You have:

```
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cl.exe", @"  'trial.cpp'");
```

Where there are spaces and single quotes in the name. Try:

```
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cl.exe", @"trial.cpp");
```

Comment: same result. it will not make much difference as I can also provide file path with quotes and extra space will just ad space in arguments which should not be a problem for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

```
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "CL.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "trial.cpp";

try
{
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch
{
    // error handling
}
```

The point here is that CL is a command line executable, not a windows GUI application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kezkeayy.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx

Comment: @Oded I apologize, but he could google and easily find the answer.

Comment: Yes. And _you_ could have commented as such.

Comment: well i have googled enough and I think everyone who posts here would be smart enough to google first and come to StackOverflow only if unable to find solutions. I can give you 5 more links with more details and more precise code, but have tried all and nothing worked hence looking for help.

Comment: @user1235483 - Nice assumption. There are plenty of questions that show that's not the case... You really should post in your questions what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If the *cl.exe* is not in the system **PATH** (which by default it is not) then the start process will not find the executable and it will fail to run.

So I suspect you are seeing the fact that the *cl.exe* is not in the system PATH.